# Using Intent(send mail) in Navigation drawer

Tags: android

I want to send mail from Navigation Drawer using the intent.
First, my MainActivity.

```
else if(id==R.id.nav_mail) {
    fragment = new MailFragment();
}
```

and MailFragment.

```
public class MailFragment extends Fragment {
public MailFragment() {
    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.setType("plain/text");
    String[] address = {"********@gmail.com"};

    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, address);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject___****");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text___****.\n\n");
    startActivity(email);
}

//  @Override
//  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
//                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//      TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
//      textView.setText(R.string.hello_blank_fragment);
//      return textView;
//  }

}
```

Run to create crash.
The reason why I used to use fragment is because I made the simple screen change function fragment.

If you need more code, comment plz.

Comment: do you import this? "import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; "

Comment: If you want to fix a crash, posting the stacktrace here is necessary for us to understand its reason. Also, the question must include the code with a line that causes the crash. Please update the question. Thanks.

Comment: show your log here

Comment: add the error logs in your question ,

Comment: Hello , @Luke Park , did you check answer.

Comment: @kdblue yeah, imported.

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin but, I don't know where crush comes. There is no red line.

Comment: @LukePark , change the code of your MailFragment as i wrote in my answer below , and then run your app and let me know further

Comment: @Thunder plz, check my comment on your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You are trying to do your logic* inside `empty public constructor` , which is wrong .

*You can perform your send email operation* inside `onViewCreated()` method. at this stage your Fragment view is created and now you perform your custom logic.

```
    public class MailFragment extends Fragment {
    public MailFragment() {

    }

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mail, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    email.setType("plain/text");
    String[] address = {"********@gmail.com"};

    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, address);
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject___****");
    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text___****.\n\n");
    startActivity(email);
    }



    }
```

Comment: I'm sorry it's the first develope, is it need layout?, too?

Comment: oh, i did it.thank you so much. I don't understand R.layout.fragment_mail part. i knew R.layout is need layout. so, i'm add other layout and write that part. thanks!

Comment: Yes , onCreateView() method needs your xml layout of that respective fragment.Hope it solves your problem

Comment: It works the way I want it to.

Comment: Great , glad to help you.

Comment: xml layout is blank, is it ok?

Comment: ya , thats up to your design , if you want to make anything then you can make it otherwise blank is also ok.

Comment: OK, thx. your so great

Comment: its alright your welcome.